# Android onQueryTextChange not showing UI changes

Tags: android, android-listview, searchview, baseadapter

When I begin typing in my `android.widget.SearchView`, I able able to find matches for the inputted text, and see that my the `Filter` from my `Adapter`, which extends `BaseAdapter`, is indeed finding results, however, I do not actually see the suggested list as I type in.

Here is what I have:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.search_card, 1, R.string.search_card);
    searchItem.setIcon(R.drawable.search);
    searchItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

    LinearLayout searchLayout = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.search_view, null);
    SearchView searchView = searchLayout.findViewById(R.id.searchVieww);
    searchItem.setActionView(searchView);
    
    //this will be a dynamic list in the end, but just wanna get it to work first...
    List<ListViewItem> suggestionList = new ArrayList<>();
    suggestionList.add(new ListViewItem("abc", "123"));
    suggestionList.add(new ListViewItem("apple", "345"));
    ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(suggestionList);
    ListView listView = searchLayout.findViewById(R.id.searchViewList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String word) {
            searchCardsForWord(word.trim());
            searchView.setIconified(true); //first call to clear search bar
            searchView.setIconified(true); //second call to close search bar
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String word) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(word);
            Log.d("DEBUG", "query text filter: " + adapter.getCount());// the count of this is NOT zero when I type in 'a'
            return false;
        }
    });

    ...adding other MenuItems

    return true;
}
```

Adapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;

import com.boredofnothing.flashcard.databinding.ListViewItemBinding;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    private List<ListViewItem> itemList;
    private List<ListViewItem> itemListFull;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    ListViewAdapter(List<ListViewItem> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        itemListFull = new ArrayList<>(itemList);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ListViewItem getItem(int position) {
        return itemList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }

    private Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            List<ListViewItem> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                filteredList.addAll(itemListFull);
            } else {
                String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                for (ListViewItem item : itemListFull) {
                    if (item.getText1().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)
                        || item.getText2().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        filteredList.add(item);
                    }
                }
            }

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filteredList;

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            itemList.clear();
            itemList.addAll((List) results.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        ListViewItemBinding listViewItemBinding = ListViewItemBinding.inflate(inflater);
        listViewItemBinding.textView1.setText(itemList.get(position).getText1());
        listViewItemBinding.textView2.setText(itemList.get(position).getText2());

        return listViewItemBinding.getRoot();
    }
}
```

search_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchVieww"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:queryHint="Input word to search"></SearchView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/searchViewList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

</LinearLayout>
```

list_view_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_view1"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Before SearchView selected:

[image]

After SerachView selected:

[image]

After typing in 'a':

[image]

In the end I would like to see a `ListView` of `Cardviews` if the inputted word/characters match or are contained in my `suggestionList`.

Comment: can you post your ListViewAdapter and how have you implemented Filter in your adapter?

Comment: @Gautam i've updated my post. the filter just checks if the inputted word/charcter exists in the now hardcoded List (this will be a dynamic list in the end but i just wanted to get this to work first)

Comment: How you add search_view to your activity? I assume this layout is not bound to your activity
LinearLayout searchLayout = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.search_view, null);
You must add it in your activity layout to show results

Answer (score 1):

I just add ListView in my activity layout

[image]

```
private SearchView searchView;
private ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search_view);
    searchView = findViewById(R.id.searchVieww);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.searchViewList);
}
```

Comment: sorry for such a trivial question, exactly what line(s) did you add to get this to work?

Comment: @mrnoobynoob I've updated my answer above with snippet code

Comment: In my case I actually ended up doing:                                                                 
 ViewGroup rootLayout = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        rootLayout.addView(searchLayout);
However I will still mark this as my accepted answer since your original comment helped me solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the way you are publishing the results.

Instead of  `itemList.clear();`just change it to

```
itemList = (List) results.values
```

What's happening is once you do clear, all the objects have same reference and hence all the data is lost and you see no results.

Comment: Unfortunately I am still getting the same output with that change...I don't see any suggested list on the UI but I do see that it is still getting the correct results from the filter...

Comment: I would suggest you debug the size of the list in publish result just before you are calling notifyDataSetChanged. If your list has items and you are notifying then you will see the results on UI